# Pegar número completo de um input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Em um `<input>`, tenho o seguinte valor:

> 00001545455

Quando recupero o mesmo com **Javascript**, ele vem sem os 4 primeiros zeros.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Eu já estou passando ele na função que estou utilizando. O problema é que quando chega na função vem sem os zeros:

```html
<a class="btnGrid bt_consulta btsAcoes" titulo="Consultar" href="javascript:;" onclick="GVScheduleCommand('gvClientes',['Consultar',3],1,[{ 'name': 'cd_cnpj_cpf', 'value': 00001545455 }], 'CPF_CNPJ' );"></a>
```

Comment: Como você está recuperando esse valor?

Comment: Tens de colocar o código que estás a usar, senão não dá para adivinhar. Dá uma olhada aqui -> https://jsfiddle.net/h565yvmr/ algo no teu código está a fazer `parse` desse `value`

Comment: Em primeiro lugar, edite sua pergunta com o código. Não o poste nos comentários. Em segundo, você esta passando o número como um número no Json, não como uma string numérica. Portanto, não há como recuperar estes 0 a esquerda, a não ser que você saiba qual o tamanho do seu campo, e então faz o padding de 0's a esquerda manualmente.

Comment: Aqui está funcionando ok

Comment: Passar o número como string deve resolver: `{ 'name': 'cd_cnpj_cpf', 'value': '00001545455' }` , não existe número com zeros na frente, para manter os zeros, deve deixá-lo como string.

Answer (score 4):

Quando defines um objeto como o que referiste na pergunta:

```
{ 'name': 'cd_cnpj_cpf', 'value': 00001545455 }
```

estás a usar o *Tipo* numérico. Ou seja se fizeres:

```
var dados = { 'name': 'cd_cnpj_cpf', 'value': 00001545455 };
typeof dados.value // vai dar "number"
dados.value // vai dar 00001545455
```

Ele dá `1545455` pois intrepreta como número. Se quiseres manter os zeros tens de usar *Tipo* string, ou seja aspas à volta desses numeros. Exemplo:

```
{ 'name': 'cd_cnpj_cpf', 'value': '00001545455' }
```

e portanto:

```
var dados = { 'name': 'cd_cnpj_cpf', 'value': '00001545455' };
typeof dados.value // vai dar "string"
dados.value // vai dar '00001545455'
```

No teu código seria:

```
<a class="btnGrid bt_consulta btsAcoes" titulo="Consultar" href="javascript:;" onclick="GVScheduleCommand('gvClientes',['Consultar',3],1,[{ 'name': 'cd_cnpj_cpf', 'value': '00001545455' }], 'CPF_CNPJ' );"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

em `jQuery` você pode fazer assim:

```js
var valor = $('input').val();
$('div').append(valor);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="00001545455 " />
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Não existe número reconhecido, matematicamente falando, começados por zeros, isso é apenas uma formatação numérica, por isso você deve colocar seu valor em formato de string, com aspas, para que ele seja mantido no formato esperado:

```
<a class="btnGrid bt_consulta btsAcoes" titulo="Consultar" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="GVScheduleCommand('gvClientes',['Consultar',3],1,[{ 'name': 'cd_cnpj_cpf', 'value': '00001545455' }], 'CPF_CNPJ' );"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar o value do elemento faça

```
var valorComZeros = document.getElementById('idDoSeuInput').value;
```

Provavelmente você está fazendo um ParseInt() e isso irá remover os zeros a esquerda.